# Grails - entityName is null

Tags: grails

Grials newbie - my boilerplate, generated view code is returning null when trying to resolve the entityName argument passed to the g:message tag. So...

```
<g:message code="default.show.label" args="[entityName]" />
```

renders as "Show null" instead of "Show [the domain class name]"

Any idea what may be going on here, or suggestions on how to diagnose this? I have been making incremental changes to both the views and the domain classes but wouldn't expect this to have made any difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

entityName is a variable and set by the set tag lib, which must placed before the message tags using this variable. e.g.

```
// first define the entity name var
<g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'test', default: 'TEST')}"/>
// display msg
<g:message code="default.show.label" args="[entityName]" />
```

maybe you forget to define this var or accidentally deleted this line of code.

Comment: sorry, not sure how to do that?

Comment: underneath the up/down vote region there is a gray check mark. you have to cklick this mark, the mark will get green and the answer was marked as useful. after that the user will get reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the above example expalined it properly. However for simple understanding you can check this:

1. Simple VARIABLE which holds some value.. to do tht we use the follwoing tag

   sf

Here, var is having : Nothing but a Variable name

and  value is having: Nothing but a Value of it.

Basically I am setting Value "User" to  the variable "entityName"

So Declaration and Initialization of variable is done.

2.Now, Usage of it--> using the Following Tag

Here, code's value "default.list.label"  represents the i18n message.properties file. Where args's value (i.e "User") will be sent as a argument.